# Birt createFactoryObject returning null when the example shouldn't have a null

Tags: groovy, birt

I am trying to create a simple Birt report following this [example](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/resources/documentation/integrating/DeDemo.java) using Groovy instead. I'm not certain if it's even possible to design reports with Groovy but I haven't been able to find a solution.
From my understanding I don't believe I need to set BIRT_HOME after version 3.7. Regardless I receive the same error with or without setting BIRT_HOME. For some reason createFactoryObject returns null so I cannot use the createDesignEngine function. I'm not sure if I need to Grab another runtime version or if I'm missing other imports because I'm using Groovy. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;

@Grab(group='org.eclipse.birt.runtime', module='org.eclipse.birt.runtime', 
version='4.5.0a')

import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.CellHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DesignConfig;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DesignElementHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DesignEngine;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.ElementFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.GridHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.IDesignEngine;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.IDesignEngineFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.ImageHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.LabelHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.ReportDesignHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.RowHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.SessionHandle;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.activity.SemanticException;

import com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale;

/**
 * Simple BIRT Design Engine API (DEAPI) demo.
 */

        // Create a session handle. This is used to manage all open designs.
        // Your app need create the session only once.


        //Configure the Engine and start the Platform
        DesignConfig config = new DesignConfig( );

        //config.setProperty("BIRT_HOME", "C:\\birtruntime\\birt-runtime-4_5_0\\ReportEngine");
        IDesignEngine engine = null;
        try{


        Platform.startup( config );
        IDesignEngineFactory factory = (IDesignEngineFactory) 
        Platform.createFactoryObject( IDesignEngineFactory.EXTENSION_DESIGN_ENGINE_FACTORY );
        engine = factory.createDesignEngine( config );

        }catch( Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the error I receive

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method createDesignEngine() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
        at sample.run(sample.groovy:42)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:377)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:366)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:589)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:332)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.access$1400(GroovyMain.java:69)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain$GroovyCommand.process(GroovyMain.java:291)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:134)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:116)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:114)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:136)
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method newSessionHandle() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method newSessionHandle() on null object
        at sample.run(sample.groovy:49)
```

Comment: Try IDesignEngineFactory factory = Platform.createFactoryObject( IDesignEngineFactory.EXTENSION_DESIGN_ENGINE_FACTORY );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evgeny recommended to place the factory creation on a single line. I did not realize it was on 2 lines when I posted it here. Regardless it was on a single line in my source code so that was not the issue.

I did not figure out how to get this piece of code to work with the groovy grab command but I did figure it out using the classpath option. First I downloaded the runtime engine on the [eclipse website](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php?build=R-R1-4_5_0-201506092134). It would be the zip file under the **Report Engine** section. You might be able to use a newer version but I got it to work with 4.5.0.

Unzip this folder somewhere and in the ReportEngine\lib folder copy all the **org.eclipse** jars along with the **flute**, **com.ibm.icu**, and **org.mozilla.javascript** jars into a separate folder like C:\birtJars. You might be able to use even less jars but I didn't want to spend the time to figure out which ones weren't needed. All I know is if I added ReportEngin\lib to the classpath there would be a linkage error from what I assume were class names that matched some java classes.

Now to get the script to run in the command line you can use

```
groovy -cp "C:\birtJars\*;." myscript.groovy
```

What I did not know at first was that if you used -cp after your groovy script then the given classpath will not be used